# Combining INSERT and CASE SQL Server Queries

Tags: sql, insert, case

Here are a couple of SQL queries that I am trying to either write as a single query or two queries. I have tried various possibilities that I could think of but non worked.

I have a blank table `tbl_Z`. I am trying to `LEFT JOIN tbl_A` and `tbl_B` and load the result into `tbl_Z` plus update the `Status` column in `tbl_Z` from `tbl_A` based on criteria in the 2 SQL statements shown here:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Z
    SELECT a.*
    FROM tbl_A a
    LEFT JOIN tbl_B b ON a.AccountNumber = b.AccountNumber
    WHERE a.Period = '09/30/2021'
      AND b.AccountNumber IS NULL

UPDATE Z
SET Status = (SELECT 
                  f.ContractDate, f.BK_Date, f.Period,
                  CASE
                      WHEN ISNULL(f.ContractDate, '1/1/1900') < ISNULL(f.BK_Date, '1/1/1900') AND f.BK_Date < ISNULL(f.Period, '1/1/1900') 
                          THEN 'Bankrupt.Attrit'
                          ELSE 'Attrit'
                  END AS Status
              FROM 
                  tbl_A f
              WHERE 
                  Period = '09/30/2021')
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to set the single `Status` column - but your subquery returns **4 (!!!)** columns - how is this supposed to work ?? And you're setting the `Status` column of a single row - but your subquery could potentially return multiple rows.......

Comment: In `update` block: join target table and source table as `from tbl_Z join tbl_A` and `set tbl_Z.Status = tbl_A.yourValue`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about fields name, just add fields name in select put the case statement in write order of fields.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Z
    SELECT -- please write your all tbl_A fields here and then place below case in write order of selection
            , 
               CASE
                 WHEN ISNULL(f.ContractDate, '1/1/1900') < ISNULL(f.BK_Date, '1/1/1900') 
                      AND f.BK_Date < ISNULL(f.Period, '1/1/1900') 
                       THEN 'Bankrupt.Attrit'
                 ELSE 'Attrit'
                 END AS Status
    FROM tbl_A a
    LEFT JOIN tbl_B b ON a.AccountNumber = b.AccountNumber
    WHERE a.Period = '09/30/2021'
      AND b.AccountNumber IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hi Farshid. Thank you for your response. However I am still getting this error when I try to run the above statements, "The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns." If I comment out the CASE Statement then the statements run fine. One thing to note here is that in my select statement there are 30 fields and I am inserting those 30 fields in tble_1. However my CASE statement has 4 fields. Does that have anything to do with the error I am getting?

Comment: @FarukAnsari what's the field name in your tbal_A that you insert into the Status field in tbl_Z?

Comment: there is no field name in tbl_A for this. The value of Status is determined by the values ContractDate, BK_Date and Period. 
WHEN ISNULL(f.ContractDate, '1/1/1900') < ISNULL(f.BK_Date, '1/1/1900') 
                      AND f.BK_Date < ISNULL(f.Period, '1/1/1900')

Comment: @FarukAnsari in this case, you should list all from fields from tbl_A like below: 
insert into tbl_z(fields names are here)
select tbl_A fields name, case .. end as status
from ...